# Python pass slice as argument

Tags: python, slice

I want to pass a slice to a function so I can select a portion of a list.  Passing as a string is preferable as I will read the required slice as a command line option from the user.

```
def select_portion(list_to_slice, slicer):
    return(list_to_slice[slicer])

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
slicer = "1:4"

print(select_portion(numbers, slicer))
```

I get the following:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

which is understandable but I don't know how to modify this to get the intended output of:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 12):

Just use `slice`:

```
def select_portion(list_to_slice, slicer):
    return(list_to_slice[slicer])

sl = slice(1, 4, None)

select_portion([1,2,3,4,5], sl)
```

Comment: This is nice but doesn't allow you to pass it in as a string?

Comment: @Sandy You could do `>>> slice(*(int(x) for x in '1:4'.split(':')]))` `slice(1, 4, None)`. But i am not sure, if this is frowned upon. If you prefer `map` instead of `list` comprehension `>>> slice(*map(int, x.split(':')))`

Comment: @hansolo it's not a great idea... any arguments can be missed... for instance `::3`, `:3:-1` or even just `:` and `::` are valid.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, i see the point

Answer (score 8):

You want the `slice` constructor. In that case, that would be `slice(1, 4, None)` (which corresponds to `1:4:`).